# Does any one know which species of insect is this one?

Tags: entomology

I found this insect, in multiple zones of Imbabura - Ecuador. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imbabura_Province

Sorry for not having something to scale with, but it's about 15 cm long.

[image: Mosca de pescar oriental macho. Male dobonsfly.]

Another picture here:
[image: Mosca de pescar oriental hembra. Female dobonsfly.]

Comment: In general, it helps identification if you add the location where on earth you found the animal.

Comment: I edited the question @Marzipanherz. It is very important!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a male dobsonfly. I know this is a male because it has long mandibles which are used in mating. Female dobsonflies have short mandibles. larval dobsonflies are called hellgramites,and it really hurts a lot when they bite you.Look here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobsonfly or here entnemdept.ufl.edu/creatures/misc/eastern_dobsonfly.htm

Comment: Yes, Megaloptera, Corydalidae, Corydalus cornutus

Comment: Just in case, does anyone know its name in Spanish?

Comment: I edited the question @peter . So I should suppose that the second photograph is a female, right?

Comment: I found the Spanish name. A dobonsfly is a "Mosca de pescar oriental"

Comment: I didn't see the second picture. when I saw the first picture, I thought "I know what that is!" and just jumped at it. The second picture is a female, the long mandibles of the male are used in mating.

Answer (score 3):

**Not** *Corydalus cornutus*. That species is only found in Eastern North America. There are several other *Corydalus* species found in that part of South America. It would require an expert in them to get a more specific ID. Note that the pictures are of two different insects as well. The one on top is a male, the bottom one a female (as the earlier answer noted, females have shorter, more robust and powerful mandibles, though males and females can each draw blood with a nip (personal experience)).